# Adding tap sound to like_button flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I've added the LikeButton package: https://pub.dev/packages/like_button

inside a RawMaterialButton() but the onPressed: () {} function is ignored.

What does work is the onTap: behaviour from the LikeButton, but this does not produce a "feedback tap sound" as the RawMaterialButton() usually does.

I would like to have the "feedback tap sound" that RawMaterialButton() typically produces when using onPressed() while tapping on LikeButton()

Code goes something like this:

```
RawMaterialButton(
            elevation: 5,
            onPressed: () {
              // this is ignored
               print(isLiked);
            },
            shape: CircleBorder(),
            fillColor: Colors.white,
            constraints: BoxConstraints.tightFor(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.17,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.17,
            ),
            child: LikeButton(
            onTap: 
                // doesn't produce feedback tap sound
                (isLiked) {
                setState(() {
                  isLiked = !isLiked;
                });

                print(isLiked);
                return Future.value(!isLiked);
              }, 
              size: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.17,
              isLiked: isLiked,
              likeBuilder: (bool isLiked) {
                return Builder(builder: (context) {
                  if (isLiked) {
                    return  Icon(
                        Icons.favorite_rounded,
                        color: Colors.red,
                        size: 4.25 *
                            MediaQuery.of(context).size.height *
                            0.01,
                     );
                  } else {
                    return Icon(
                      Icons.favorite_outline_rounded,
                      color: Colors.grey,
                      size:
                          4.25 * MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.01,
                    );
                  }
                });
              },

              
            ), 

          ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by adding:

```
Feedback.forTap(context);
```

into LikeButton(onTap:

The need to do this is that LikeButton deals with GestureDetector() which does not produce a Feedback sound by default.

Reference: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Feedback-class.html

Answer (score 0):

try wrapping your button with `Inkwell` with empty tap function like this

```
child: Inkwell(onTap:(){},
               child:LikeButton(
```

and if this doesn't work or the Inkwell prevent the action from passing to the child button

you still have to option

1- access to the source code of the library and change the widget responsible for the tap into `Inkwell`

2- play custom sound in your  LikeButton's onTap using [this package](https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers) and more about how to use this package in the docs and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56377942/flutter-play-sound-on-button-press) post