# i cant add a sound to the button.in my flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart

i'm building a flutter app. and I also found `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56377942/flutter-play-sound-on-button-press` this for to do it. but I getting error. the error is like this. [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxHsu.png)
my requirement is "when I press a button I need to add a custom sound to it."
is this is the only way or any other way to done this?? please help....

also my code don't have any errors. After I adding this code this happened.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend getting the latest version of the audioplayers package from:
[audioplayers](https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers)

Next, run the following commands

- flutter doctor
- flutter clean
- flutter pub get

This will refresh your project just in case the dependency wasn't added correctly.