# How to play sound when the current tab is changed in a TabBar

Tags: flutter

How do I add a sound when the current tab is changed on a TabBar.

If I just have to play an audio file, where do I find this file on internet?

I tried to use `enableFeedback`, but it seems like it has no effect on iOS.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to play sound on button press](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56377942/how-to-play-sound-on-button-press)